# Wierd character in zsh

Tags: zsh

I have problem with zsh at command line for non English language characters
but after enter key the language show the right word.

```
~   
❯ สว<0e31>สด<0e35>
สวัสดี
zsh: command not found: สวัสดี
```

i was check the locale everything is utf8

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and check if any fonts, it's have same problem.
i use **zsh** *version 5.0.2* and **oh-my-zh**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer.

Open `~/.zshrc` file and add this option below at the end of file:

```
setopt COMBINING_CHARS
```

Then restart Terminal.